# Chain connect/mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps functions for code reuse in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Say I have two redux connected components. The first is a simple todo loading/display container, with the following functions passed to `connect()`; `mapStateToProps` reads the todos from the redux state, and `mapDispatchToProps` is used to request the state to be provided the latest list of todos from the server:

## TodoWidgetContainer.js

```
import TodoWidgetDisplayComponent from '...'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: todoSelectors.getTodos(state)
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    refreshTodos: () => dispatch(todoActions.refreshTodos())
  };
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchTo)(TodoWidgetDisplayComponent);
```

The second redux component is intended to be applied to any component on a page so that component can indicate whether a global "loading" icon is displayed. Since this can be used anywhere, I created a helper function that wraps `MapDispatchToProps` in a closure and generates an ID for each component, which is used to make sure all components that requested the loader indicate that they don't need it anymore, and the global loader can be hidden.

The functions are basically as follows, with `mapStateToProps` exposing the loader visibility to the components, and `mapDispatchToProps` allowing them to request the loader to show or hide.

## Loadify.js

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    openLoader: loaderSelectors.getLoaderState(state)
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps() {
  const uniqId = v4();
  return function(dispatch) {
    return {
      showLoader: () => {
        dispatch(loaderActions.showLoader(uniqId));
      },
      hideLoader: () => {
        dispatch(loaderActions.hideLoader(uniqId));
      }
    };
  };
}

export default function Loadify(component) {
  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(component);
}
```

So now, if I have a component that I want to give access to the loader, I can just do something like this:

```
import Loadify from '...'

class DisplayComponent = new React.Component { ... }

export default Loadify(DisplayComponent);
```

And it should give it a unique ID, allow it to request the loader to show/hide, and as long as there is one component that is requesting it to show, the loader icon will show. So far, this all appears to be working fine.

My question is, if I would like to apply this to the todos component, so that that component can request/receive its todos while also being allowed to request the loader to show while it is processing, could I just do something like:

## TodoWidgetContainer.js

```
import Loadify from '...'
import TodoWidgetDisplayComponent from '...'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: todoSelectors.getTodos(state)
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    refreshTodos: () => dispatch(todoActions.refreshTodos())
  };
}

const TodoContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchTo)(TodoWidgetDisplayComponent);

export default Loadify(TodoContainer);
```

And will redux automatically merge the objects together to make them compatible, assuming there are no duplicate keys? Or will it take only the most recent set of `mapStateToProps`/`mapDispatchTo` unless I do some sort of manual merging? Or is there a better way to get this kind of re-usability that I'm not seeing? I'd really rather avoid having to create a custom set of containers for every component we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` will automatically merge together the combination of  "props passed to the wrapper component", "props from this component's `mapState`", and "props from this component's `mapDispatch`".  The default implementation of that logic is simply:

```
export function defaultMergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  return { ...ownProps, ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps }
}
```

So, if you stack multiple levels of `connect` around each other , the wrapped component will receive *all* of those props as long as they don't have the same name.  If any of those props do have the same name, then only one of them would show up, based on this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is what I would do. Create a higher order component (HOC) that adds a new spinner reference to your reducer. The HOC will initialize and destroy references to the spinner in redux by tying into the life cycle methods. The HOC will provide two properties to the base component. The first is `isLoading` which is a function that takes a boolean parameter; true is on, false is off. The second property is `spinnerState` that is a readonly boolean of the current state of the spinner.

I created this example without the action creators or reducers, let me know if you need an example of them.

#### loadify.jsx

```
/*----------  Vendor Imports  ----------*/
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import v4 from 'uuid/v4';

/*----------  Action Creators  ----------*/
import {
  initNewSpinner,
  unloadSpinner,
  toggleSpinnerState,
} from '@/wherever/your/actions/are'


const loadify = (Component) => {
  class Loadify extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.uniqueId = v4();
      props.initNewSpinner(this.uniqueId);;
      this.isLoading = this.isLoading.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.unloadSpinner(this.uniqueId);
    }

    // true is loading, false is not loading
    isLoading(isOnBoolean) {
      this.props.toggleSpinner(this.uniqueId, isOnBoolean);
    }

    render() {
      // spinners is an object with the uuid as it's key
      // the value to the key is weather or not the spinner is on.
      const { spinners } = this.props;
      const spinnerState = spinners[this.uniqueId];
      return (
        <Component isLoading={this.isLoading} spinnerState={spinnerState}  />
      );
    }

  }

  const mapStateTopProps = state => ({
    spinners: state.ui.spinners,
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    initNewSpinner: uuid => dispatch(initNewSpinner(uuid)),
    unloadSpinner: uuid => dispatch(unloadSpinner(uuid)),
    toggleSpinner: (uuid, isOn) => dispatch(toggleSpinnerState(uuid, isOn))
  })

  return connect(mapStateTopProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Loadify);

};

export default loadify;
```

#### Use Case Example

```
import loadify from '@/location/loadify';
import Spinner from '@/location/SpinnerComponent';

class Todo extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.isLoading(true);
    asyncCall.then(response => {
      // process response
      this.props.isLoading(false);
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { spinnerState } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Spinner Testing Component</h1>
        { spinnerState && <Spinner /> }
      </div>
    );
  }

}

// Use whatever state you need
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  whatever: state.whatever.youneed,
});

// use whatever dispatch you need
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  doAthing: () => dispatch(doAthing()),
});

// Export enhanced Todo Component
export default loadify(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todo));
```